# Is there any way to analyze an absurdly large exponent?

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics, exponentiation

On a recent [Giant Bombcast](http://www.giantbomb.com/podcasts/giant-bombcast-03-04-2014/1600-781/), someone wrote in and asked an absurd question (as is usual for this podcast). In short, the question was:

> Given a 1080p TV, how long would it take to view every possible image?

(The guys on the podcast eventually concluded that it would take longer than the lifespan of the universe. On the next episode, someone else wrote in and said that it would take "the lifetime of the universe infinity times over". However, this is not the focus of the question.)

This question effectively boils down to:

$$
n = (256^3) ^ {1920 \times 1080}
$$

Or

$$
n = 16777216^{2073600}
$$

This is obviously an incomprehensibly large number. I suspect that it has billions of digits and such. However, is there any way to figure out any properties of it without having to actually calculate it? Like, is it possible to figure out what it would be in scientific notation? Or something like that?

Comment: Take the logarithm to base $10$ - that will give you the number of digits and the most significant figures

Comment: *This is obviously an incomprehensibly large number.* - No. It isn't. It [really](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham's_number) isn't.

Comment: There is an essay by Isaac Asimov, “Skewered!”, in which he tries to make sense of Skewes' number, $$10^{10^{10^{34}}},$$ which at that time  was supposed to be the largest number that had ever appeared in a mathematical proof. Skewes' number is *vastly* larger than your $n$, and although Asimov didn't really get close to it, you may find his techniques useful for understanding your much smaller $n$, which is only around $10^{10^7}$ or so.

Comment: A comment just in case interesting. I once taught from a thermal physics textbook in which numbers were said to be either "small" (like 23) or "large" (like $10^{23}$) or "very large" (like $10^{10^{23}}$ or your number). The point is that for physics purposes, adding a small number to a large number doesn't change the large number ($23 + 10^{23} \approx 10^{23}$). And multiplying a very large number by a large number doesn't change it ($10^{23} \times 10^{10^{23}} \approx 10^{10^{23}}$). (The book is http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Thermal-Physics-Daniel-Schroeder/dp/0201380277.)

Comment: *Someone wrote in and asked an absurd question: Given a 1080p TV, how long would it take to view every possible image?* - The realization I've had (whilst suffering from depression, no less) was that the number of movies is finite: Since all movies up to two hours in length can fit into $700$ MB of data, the there are no more than $2^{700\cdot10^6}$ stories/ideas/etc out there. It felt really... depressing.

Comment: The Netflix of Babel....

Comment: From my 8 April 2002 sci.math post [Big Numbers #3](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=379996) (^^ is the tetration operation): To motivate what follows, here is one way to describe how big the number 10^^(10^^4) is. Let n be one googolplex. That is, n = 10^(10^100). Now consider n!!!...!, where the factorial operation is applied over and over again, a googolplex number of times. The result will be much less than 10^^(10^^4). In fact, 10^^(10^^4) is [roughly] what you'd get if you applied the factorial operation 10^(10^10,000,000,000) many times to a googolplex.

Comment: @Lucian I'm familiar with (the concept of) Graham's number. It's existence doesn't make the number here any more comprehensible :)

Comment: Am I correct that $n = 16777216^{2073600}$ is around $ n = 10 ^{7 \times 20736000} $ is around $ n = 10 ^ {10 ^ 9}$ ps this is just a very rough estimate, see it more as a question do i use the right method.

Comment: @Willemien: Not really, it's around $10^{14981179}\approx10^{10^{7.17}}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This 14,981,180-digit number is $2^{49766400}$ which is $1.50041692264871365956211935\ldots\times10^{14981179}$ in scientific notation. Its final digits are ...26416858621186596199148240803900704079262350188482842853376.

I'll try to put this in human terms, but it's not going to make it any easier. This is roughly the number of ways to choose a team of four million people from all of the earth.

Comment: I am a little disappointed that this does not in fact have billions of digits.

Comment: Also +1(when the time limit is lifted) for the final digits.

Comment: Neat! Out of curiosity, how did you come up with this? I am a programmer, and the program I wrote to figure this out by brute force did not complete in the hour I gave it.

Comment: @MikeCaron: I used PARI/GP ( http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr ) to do the calculations. It can hold the full number in floating-point (what it calls a t_REAL) so I just copied directly from that. I used its `Mod` command to find the last hundred digits (then trimmed it down to fit nicely). I had to write a custom program to get the "choose a team" figure, as those numbers were so large they were overflowing its internal representation.

Comment: @mike It is not at all difficult to calculate $a^b\bmod n$ when $n$ is not excessively large.  You can calculate $a^b$ using around $\log_2 b$ multiplications, which in this case is only 25 or 26,  and you only need to store around $4\log_2 n$ bits at any time, which in this case is around 400.  Do you know the trick for fast exponentiation?